# how can one distinguish JS Opaque Objects?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, scala.js, webcrypto-api

The [WebCrypto API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#SubtleCrypto-method-generateKey) introduces the notion of non exportable private keys, which can be exported to IndexDB but not not LocalStorage or over the web. This is nicely explained in Charles Engleke's blog "[Saving Cryptographic Keys in the Browser](http://blog.engelke.com/2014/09/19/saving-cryptographic-keys-in-the-browser/)".

But how do these objects actually work? Is there a way to tell from JS if an object is opaque or not? I am having trouble finding any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a magical "opaque flag" anywhere. "Opaque" here just means there is data held in the object that is *never* visible to script. You can still perform some operations with a `CryptoKey` instance - e.g. in this case, store it in Indexed DB or send to another context via `postMessage()`.

This is in contrast to e.g. a `Blob` object where *all* of the held data can be inspected either directly via attributes on the object or indirectly via a `FileReader`.

Another opaque example would be a `Response` object as a result of a cross-origin [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) operation, which can be processed by a [Service Worker](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/) but where the body can't be inspected.

So "is there a way to tell from JS if an object is opaque?" - it depends.  If an object is an instance of `CryptoKey` then you know there is hidden data, so it is opaque. If an object is an instance of `Blob` then you know there is a way to access the data, even if you need other APIs to get access to it, so it is not opaque. If an object is an instance of `Response` it may be opaque, depending on the source.

Comment: Btw. the reason this came up was that I was trying to find a way to use a scala-js library to write such opaque objects to IndexDB. The library was serialising these objects and I was trying to find a general solution to avoid such serialisation for opaque objects. The answer was to remove the serialisation code and require pure JS objects to be written to the database. I did this here https://github.com/bblfish/scalajs-rx-idb/