# What is an opaque object?

Tags: javascript

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload

> The `XMLHttpRequest` `upload` property returns an `XMLHttpRequestUpload` object that can be observed to monitor an upload's progress. **It is an opaque object**, but because it's also an `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget`, event listeners can be attached to track its process.

What is an "opaque object" and what does it mean here based on the context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can one distinguish JS Opaque Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971634/how-can-one-distinguish-js-opaque-objects)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type

Comment: @Leon I read that post but I wasn't sure they're talking about the same thing.

Comment: I assume that they mean that the `XMLHttpRequestUpload` is an object whose internal structure is invisible to us (opaque), however, being also a `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget` it exposes some event handlers (i.e. `onload`, `onabort`) that can be used to attach events.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ok I read that page too but that seems not be specific to js. So does it mean that *opaque object* is a genernal progamming  concept?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Oh thanks, that makes more sense:)

Comment: @Rick I'll give you your question, reversed: can you list programming concepts that are **specific** to JS? Most programming concepts are general... I'd bet that *opaque* is such a case.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Good question.. Got it thanks.

Comment: @YoavKadosh You can move your comment to answer. I think that's what Mozilla doc means :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that they mean that the `XMLHttpRequestUpload` is an object whose internal structure is invisible to us (opaque). However, being also a `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget` it exposes some event handlers (i.e. `onload`, `onabort`) that can be used to attach events.